# Cost of production plant

Tags: macroeconomics, data-request, paneldata

I'm struggling to find a macroeconomic index which embodies the cost to run an average production plan.

My problem is that I wanted to divide the annual average cost per employee (which I already found to be `gross income per capita`) with the cost of running an average asset (e.g rent, energy and other expenses).

Did such an index exists?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for data on costs for production plants you might consider the BLS productivity data https://www.bls.gov/mfp/mprdload.htm.

Under the combined sector and industry multifactor productivity excel file you can find cost measures organized by NAICS (North American Industry Classification System) at the three digit level [https://www.census.gov/cgi-bin/sssd/naics/naicsrch?chart=2012] .

Depending on what type of production plant you are looking for there is data by energy usage, rent, and other types of costs.